# Talking about animals of the same type

Tags: grammar

I have trouble expressing my thoughts when talking about animals that belong to the same kind. Is it correct to say

"It appears that certain behavior shared by animals of the same kind is due to..."

and

"They investigated the behavior of several animal classes, namely birds, snakes and fish."

Comment: I'd say the plural form would be more felicitous in your second sentence, without context.

Comment: Both are correct grammatically. In the first sentence though, you might want to replace "of the same kind" by "species" or some other more technical term based on what you intend to say. In the second sentence, you might want to verify that birds, snakes, and fish are in the same "class", as defined in standard biological taxonomy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy_(biology)